# How to add spacing between slides in react-slick without using padding?

Tags: css, reactjs, slider, spacing, react-slick

I am using `react-slick` to create a slider in my React project. I am displaying three slides at a time. I want to add some space between these slides, but I'd like to avoid using padding. How can I achieve this?

Here's the relevant code:

```js
const settings = {
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        initialSlide: 2,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
      },
    },
  ],
};
return(
<div>
<Slider {...settings} className="w-full">
        {movie
          .filter((item) => item.rating >= 7.5)
          .map((item) => (
            <div className="relative shadow-2xl" key={item.id}>
              <img
                onClick={() =>
                  handleOpenMovie(
                    item.img,
                    item.title,
                    item.rating,
                    item.genre,
                    item.matter
                  )
                }
                className="w-full h-72 mobile:h-44 tablet:h-44 rounded-xl hover:-translate-y-0.5 hover:scale-105 transition ease-in-out delay-150 duration-500 cursor-pointer"
                src={item.img}
                alt=""
              />
              <div className="flex items-center absolute bottom-1 left-1 right-1 font-barlow p-1 justify-between">
                <span className="text-white text-2xl font-semibold">
                  {item.title}
                </span>
                <div>
                  <span className="bg-green-900 text-white font-semibold p-2 rounded-full ">
                    {item.rating}
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </Slider>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr9y4.jpg)

I tried adjusting the slidesToShow and slidesToScroll properties in the react-slick settings. I also looked into the react-slick documentation to see if there was a property specifically for spacing between slides but didn't find any. I also considered using padding, but I want to avoid this approach as I'd prefer a cleaner method that doesn't affect the actual slide content size.

Comment: I only help with CSS rather than JS, but because you didn't post a working demo, I can only suggest you try playing around with the CSS `gap` property, which applies to flex items these days.

Comment: "method that doesn't affect the actual slide content size" - does box-sizing help here?